# How can I play a .drv file

Tags: macos, video

I received several .drv files recorded from a security system's cameras. The disc provided to me includes a player called "GenAVplayer.exe" and a filed named "player.bin" which when expanded contains .dll files, I assume various codecs for the player. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can play these video clips on my Mac?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend either [MPlayerX](http://mplayerx.org) or [VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org). Both are freely downloadable and support a variety of audio and video codecs. If you're *lucky* one might just work!

Comment: As it turns out, I was not lucky with that disc. But VideoLAN did help me with another similar disc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running GenAVplayer in wine, and opening the files in that.